# Failing 2x4 "ledger" board

Tags: repair, deck, carpentry, ledger

[image: 2x4 boards nailed into either joists or double plate]

My deck is currently failing due to the fact that it is supported by 2x4 boards nailed into what is either a double plate below the floor joists or the end grain of the joists themselves, there is no band joist.

The deck joists are just sitting on those 2x4 boards.

I have put a stack of 4x4's beneath the deck to help support the load for now.

In the most affected spot, the deck is about 1.5 inches away from the house and 2 inches down.

The rest of the deck is supported with posts and concrete poured below frost depth.

I am thinking I have 2 options.

Option 1- cut back the siding and install a proper ledger board by putting in blocking and using DTT2Z brackets with threaded rod connecting house joists to deck joists. This would likely also mean cutting the joists a little bit to ensure a proper fit when the new ledger is in place.

Option 2- Make the deck free-standing. this would involve digging 48" holes for the frost footings and it is pretty tight under the deck so I would prefer option 1.

Does anybody have any wisdom to share about anything I should do differently?

Is this even the right way to go about this sort of thing?

Upper portion of second picture is where blocking and tension ties would be installed

[image: this is in the crawl space where the blocking and tension ties would be installed]

Comment: Check with your building department.  A free standing(not attached to the house) deck might not need frost footings.

Comment: @crip659 the codes for decks specify 3'6" below grade, it looks like they treat free standing the same as attached for the footings.

Comment: Sounds like they are like my town.